Envio de formData en react, falla al cargar archivos
Tengo un problema al enviar datos a desde mi frontend, cuando cargo los datos en mi archivo en un formData, este se completa de manera correcta y tengo archivos file configurados para enviar
formDataToSend, no los almacena de manera correcta, esta es la función onSubmit 
const onSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Datos del formData", formData, postMainImage)
        if (postMainImage) {
            let formDataToSend = new FormData();

            // Agregar campos de texto
            formDataToSend.append('name', formData.name);
            formDataToSend.append('description', formData.description);
            formDataToSend.append('brand', formData.brand);
            formDataToSend.append('model', formData.model);
            formDataToSend.append('serial', formData.serial);
            formDataToSend.append('color', formData.color);
            formDataToSend.append('size', formData.size);
            formDataToSend.append('mainImage', postMainImage);
            
            if (postBackImage && postBackImage.image) {
                formDataToSend.append('backImage', postBackImage);
            }
            if (postLeftImage && postLeftImage.image) {
                formDataToSend.append('leftImage', postLeftImage);
            }
            if (postRightImage && postRightImage.image) {
                formDataToSend.append('rightImage', postRightImage);
            }

            console.log("Datos del formDataToSend:",formDataToSend);
            await upload_good(formDataToSend);
        }
    };

Ademas de eso tengo una accion de redux, la cual recibe los datos de un FormData para enviarlos de igual manera, que es la siguiente:
export const upload_good = (goodData) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: SET_GOOD_LOADING
    });

    if(localStorage.getItem('access')){
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        };

        const formData = new FormData();
        for (const key in goodData) {
            if (goodData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                formData.append(key, goodData[key]);
            }
        }
    
        console.log("Datos a enviar al backend:", formData);

        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/good/upload`, formData, config);

            if (res.status === 201) {
                dispatch({
                    type: UPLOAD_GOOD_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                });
                dispatch(setAlert('Tu bien ha sido registrado correctamente', 'good'))
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: UPLOAD_GOOD_FAIL
                });
                dispatch(setAlert('Error al registrar el bien.', 'bad'))
            }
            dispatch({
                type: REMOVE_GOOD_LOADING
            });
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: UPLOAD_GOOD_FAIL
            });
            dispatch({
                type: REMOVE_GOOD_LOADING
            });
            dispatch(setAlert('Error conectando con el servidor, intenta mas tarde', 'bad'))
        }
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: REMOVE_GOOD_LOADING
        });
        dispatch({
            type: UPLOAD_GOOD_FAIL
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Error de autenticación, inicia sesión antes de continuar', 'bad'))
    };
};

Que tiene un console.log al igual que las demas funciones, para controlar que datos se guardan y que datos no.
Y el resultado en consola es el siguiente:
Datos del formData {name: 'Acolchado', description: 'Acolchado nido de abeja azul quemado en la punta', brand: 'Acol', model: 'A1011', serial: '', …}brand: "Acol"color: "Azul"description: "Acolchado nido de abeja azul quemado en la punta"model: "A1011"name: "Acolchado"serial: ""size: ""[[Prototype]]: Object FileList {0: File, length: 1}0: File {name: 'cubrecama-nido-de-abeja-azul-marino-jpg1-6785c10f0b89320fe316662101751101-640-0.png', lastModified: 1710768306995, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 18 2024 10:25:06 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 823607, …}length: 1[[Prototype]]: FileList
UploadNewGood.jsx:118 Datos del formDataToSend: FormData {}[[Prototype]]: FormData
good.js:39 Datos a enviar al backend: FormData {}[[Prototype]]: FormData

Donde el primer formData tiene datos pero no se cargan ni se envian de forma correcta
